# Why is "err != nil"?

Tags: go

I have a situation where the value of a variable "err error" value can only be "nil" but asserts "( err == nil ) == false" once it has been reassigned.

Example code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type TestError struct {
    Message string
}

func (e *TestError) Error() string {
    return e.Message
}

func NewTestError(err error) *TestError {
    if err == nil {
            return nil
    }
    log.Printf("NewTestError( ... ): creating new NewTestError err = %s", err)
    return &TestError{Message: err.Error()}
}

func main() {
    var err error
    _, err = fmt.Printf("excuse.\n")
    err = NewTestError(err)
    log.Printf("main( ... ): err == nil. %v", (err == nil))
    log.Printf("main( ... ): err = %#v", err)
}
```

I get the following output from the above code:

```
excuse.
2015/07/30 08:28:28 main( ... ): err == nil. false
2015/07/30 08:28:28 main( ... ): err = (*main.TestError)(nil)
```

How can those last two lines be output?

Comment: http://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error

Answer (score 2):

For an interface value (like an `error` value) to compare equal to `nil`, both the actual contained value and the actual contained type have to be `nil`. In your case you have an interface value, which holds a `nil` pointer, but a `*TestError` (i.e. non-`nil`) type.

PS. Just in case it's not clear what are these "interface values", you can check this http://research.swtch.com/interfaces

Comment: Is there a generic non-interface pointer type that both objects can be cast to for the purpose of comparison?

Answer (score 0):

In the second case you're printing the interface instances information which is the type and the value, type being `(*main.TestError)` value being `(nil)`. In the first case what you're actually comparing isn't `nil` because it's also the interface.